# make image width responsive to parent div

Tags: html, css

This is my current html (it is actually jade) set up:

```
.format-properly
    .guide-bg-warrior.img-responsive
```

Which could be translated into:

```
<div class="format-properly">
    <div class="guide-bg-warrior img-responsive>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `img-responsive` class is from bootstrap and this is the other part of my css:

```
.format-properly {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: .0em;
}

.guide-bg-warrior{
    background-image:url('images/hero_images/warriorbg.png');
}
```

So the image is getting loaded but it is not getting scaled to the `format-properly` divs width. Do you guys have any suggestions on why this could be the case?

Comment: That is because `img-responsive` is class that works on `img` element and not on `background` of some element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add

```
.guide-bg-warrior{
    background-image:url('images/hero_images/warriorbg.png');
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Or, if you really want your image to cover all the div:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Wow that was surprisingly easy! Thank your for your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
.guide-bg-warrior{
background-image:url('images/hero_images/warriorbg.png');
background-size:100% auto;
```

}

or you want to cover all div then use

```
.guide-bg-warrior{
    background-image:url('images/hero_images/warriorbg.png');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `img-responsive` class it must be on `img` element like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/171/

**HTML**

```
<div class="format-properly">
   <div class="guide-bg-warrior">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.format-properly {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: .0em;
}
```